# Help in evaluating an integral of exponential function

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function

I am trying to evaluate the following integral
$$ I = \int_{0}^{t}s^{-b-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2} a^2 s^{-2 b}} ds$$
where $a > 0$ and $ 0 \le b \le 1$.

I am not quite sure how to solve this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am getting a solution in terms of $\text{erf}(x)$. Is there any particular reason to expect this integral to be expressible in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: If you let $a= \sigma$, this almost looks the characteristic function of a normal distribution with variance $\sigma^2$. Since the error function is related to the CDF of the normal distribution, I think your result @Fimpellizieri is perfectly natural.

Comment: A solution in form of the erf would be acceptable to me. I came across this integral while studying a Cumulative distribution function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Enforce the substitution $s\to s^{-1/b}$ to yield the integral

$$\frac1b \int_{t^{-1/b}}^\infty e^{-\frac12 a^2s^s}\,ds$$